# matrix customize shape not fit with other cells

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I try to use a customized shape (crossed rectangle) as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    module/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum size=1em,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
    mycross/.style={path picture={
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) --  (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west);
    }}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{column align/.style 2 args={column #1/.append style={nodes={execute at begin
                    node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
                    execute at end
                    node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][#2]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}}}
    \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={module}, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ]
    {
        Y & Y & Y \\
        Y & Y & |[mycross]|  \\
        Y & Y & Y \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

But the the customized cell not fit with other cells, and I wish to add a red background with red!30 color as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add `anchor=center`. That is replace `nodes={module}` by `nodes={module,anchor=center}` to get

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}
\tikzset{
    module/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum size=1em,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
    mycross/.style={path picture={
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) --  (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west);
    }}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{column align/.style 2 args={column #1/.append style={nodes={execute at begin
                    node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
                    execute at end
                    node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][#2]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}}}
    \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={module,anchor=center}, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ]
    {
        Y & Y & Y \\
        Y & Y & |[mycross]|  \\
        Y & Y & Y \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, in the current use case the document can be reduced to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    module/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum size=1em,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
    mycross/.style={path picture={
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) --  (path picture bounding box.north east);
        \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west);
    }}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={module,anchor=center}, 
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ]
    {
        Y & Y & Y \\
        Y & Y & |[mycross]|  \\
        Y & Y & Y \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

In particular, `column align` is not used, and if you want to use it, make sure to load the `eqmakebox` package.

Comment: Great answer! How to fill background within that cell?

Comment: @lucky1928 Just replace `|[mycross]|` by `|[mycross,fill=blue!20]|`, say. You can fill any cell by adding `|[fill=...]|` to that cell.